# Counterexample to converse of Fubinis theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Given $f(x,y)=\dfrac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ and the Gaussian measure $\mu$ with expected value 0 and variance 1, show that $\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,y)\mu(dx)\mu(dy)=\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,y)\mu(dy)\mu(dx)$ but $\int_\mathbb{R^2}f(x,y)(\mu\otimes\mu)(dx\times dy)$ does not exist.

I know what this boils down to, showing that $\int_\mathbb{R}^2 |f(x,y)|(\mu\otimes\mu)(dx\times dy)=\infty$. I am mainly having trouble with the notation: I am assuming $\mu(dx)=d\mu(x)$ is just a ways to emphasize we are "measuring the size" of very small $x$ with respect to $\mu$. How do I go about calculating the two iterative integrals? I know that $\mu(A)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{A}\exp(-\dfrac{x^2}{2})dx$. Does that mean I have to calculate $\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,y)\exp(-\dfrac{x^2}{2})\exp(-\dfrac{y^2}{2})dxdy$? How do I interpret $\mu\otimes\mu$ in terms of actually calculating integrals with it?

Edit: I found a theorem that says: If $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable and $F$ continously differentiable with $F'=f$ then $\int udF=\int u(x)f(x)dx$. This answers the first part, both come out to $0$.

I'm still stuck at showing the third integral is not finite: I plotted the function and see that in every quadrant the absolute value of the function goes to infinity as we get closer to $0$, but I am at a loss on how to show this formally.

Comment: Yes, that is the (iterated) integral you have to compute (and the one with the other order of integration). Disregarding niceties about completion of measures, $(\mu\otimes\mu)(dx\times dy)$ (yuck, I detest that notation) means you need to compute $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) \exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)\, d\lambda^2,$$ where $\lambda^2$ is the (two-dimensional) Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ - if that integral exists, of course, here it doesn't.

Comment: I am sorry about the notation, it is not my personal favorite either. So basically we use that $(\mu\otimes\mu)(A_1\times A_2):=\mu(A_1)\cdot\mu(A_2)$ by definition?

Comment: I know you didn't choose it. You wouldn't ask about it if it were your be-all-and-end-all. Basically, if $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are given by densities $\rho_1,\rho_2$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the factors, then $\mu_1\otimes \mu_2$ is given by the density $\rho(x,y) = \rho_1(x)\cdot \rho_2(y)$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the product space. [Strictly, that is the completion of $\mu_1\otimes \mu_2$, but for practical purposes, you can ignore the distinction].